# Why react-native Swipeout not working?

Tags: listview, swipe, react-native

I am working on react-native Swipeout but after adding the npm package, but it's showing some error, i am posting the error message screenshots please go through it below.

[image]

npm install react-native-swipeout

```
npm install --save react-native-swipeout
```

imported Packages

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

import Swipeout from 'react-native-swipeout';
```

Code

```
let swipeBtns = [{
    text: 'Delete',
    backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
}];
<Swipeout 
   right={swipeBtns}>
    <View>
       <Text style={styles.items_name_txt}>{rowData.name}</Text>
       <View style={styles.items_list_view_line}></View>
    </View>
</Swipeout>
```

Please kindly go through my code and suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work anymore because React Native has changed significantly since its introduction. The library owner updated the package, but did not publish the new changes.

Change your package.json to
"react-native-swipeout": "https://github.com/dancormier/react-native-swipeout.git"

This should fix your problem